# R how to group by a string (text rating) in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
Name      Term    Grade
David     Spring  A
Mike      Spring  B
Sherry    Fall    A+
Paul      Fall    D
Joy       Fall    C
Ken       Spring  B+
```

I want to group by Grade column and see how many students have A, B, C etc.

I'm using

```
grading = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
grading_agg = sapply(grading, function(x) {
    sum(grepl(x, df$Grade))
})
```

Which returns me

```
A  B  C  D   
2  2  1  1
```

I want to know how many A, B, C, D in Spring and Fall respectively. I'm expecting something like

```
       Grade  A   B   C   D
Term  
Spring        1   2   0   0
Fall          1   0   1   1
```

I'm trying aggregate function but it's not working as I expected. I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` after removing the `+/-` from the 'Grade' with `sub`

```
table(transform(df1, Grade = sub("[+-]", "", Grade))[-1])
#        Grade
#Term     A B C D
#  Fall   1 0 1 1
#  Spring 1 2 0 0
```

---

or using `tidyverse`, we get the `count` of 'Term' and substring of 'Grade', `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  count(Term, Grade = str_remove(Grade, "[+-]")) %>% 
  spread(Grade, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Term       A     B     C     D
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Fall       1     0     1     1
#2 Spring     1     2     0     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("David", "Mike", "Sherry", "Paul", "Joy", 
"Ken"), Term = c("Spring", "Spring", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", 
"Spring"), Grade = c("A", "B", "A+", "D", "C", "B+")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Term", "Grade"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: table(transform()) works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Kenneth You can accept the answer by clicking on `tick` symbol in left of answer box if it has worked for you. Thanks.